# get value of dynamic add textbox

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have two file `test.py` and `test.kv`
In test.kv  `text: "+Add More"` which add row dynamic vertical position.I am creating dynamic id in .py

```
self.add_widget(Row(button_text=str(self.row_count),id=str("test"+str(self.row_count))))
```

and in .kv file i am assigning id

```
id : root.id
```

Can anyone tell me how to get all dynamic value `value1,value2,value3` in `.py` file
Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated..!!

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

## test.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ListProperty, StringProperty, ObjectProperty, NumericProperty

Window.size = (450, 525)


class display(Screen):

    def add_more(self):
        self.ids.rows.add_row()

    def insert_value(self):
        print(Row().id)
        #print(self.ids.)



class Row(BoxLayout):
    button_text = StringProperty("")
    id = ObjectProperty(None)



class Rows(BoxLayout):
    orientation = "vertical"
    row_count = 0

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Rows, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_row()

    def add_row(self):
        self.row_count += 1
        self.add_widget(Row(button_text=str(self.row_count),id=str("test"+str(self.row_count))))


class test(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('test.kv')
        return self.root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test().run()
```

## test.kv

```
<Row>:
    #state1 : state1
    orientation: "horizontal"
    spacing: 0, 5

    Button:
        text: root.button_text
        size_hint_x: .2

    TextInput:
        #text : root.id
        size_hint_x: .8
        id : root.id

display:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding : 20, 20

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"

            Button:
                size_hint_x: .2
                text: "+Add More"
                valign: 'bottom'
                on_press: root.add_more()


        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .2
                text: "SN"
                valign: 'bottom'

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .8
                text: "Value"
                valign: 'bottom'


        Rows:
            id: rows

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            padding : 10, 0
            spacing: 10, 10
            size_hint: .5, .7
            pos_hint: {'x': .25, 'y':.25}

            Button:
                text: 'Ok'
                on_release:
                    root.insert_value()

            Button:
                text: 'Cancel'
                on_release: root.dismiss()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you must access `Rows` for it we use ids since he has an id:

```
    Rows:
        id: rows
```

Then you access each `Row` through children since when you use add_widget is stored in this `ListProperty`, and the same is done with Row but `isinstance()` is used to filter the `TextInput`, after that the text is obtained and added to the list.

It should be noted that the oldest children are at the end because of it `reversed()` is used.

```
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
[...]

    def insert_value(self):
        values = []
        rows = self.ids.rows
        for row in reversed(rows.children):
            for ch in row.children:
                if isinstance(ch, TextInput):
                    values.append(ch.text)
        print(values)
```

Comment: Thanks for your Efford it really helped me a lot :)