# using add_widget to generate TextInput and reference it later on Kivy, Python , no id

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I was wrong i got to do one more update:
The Accepted Answer now includes one way to reference generated Textinput by add_widget, so my Link is still an alternative but by editing the Answer theres a Solution much for all those of you who would like to stick with weakref and maybe its a nice way to start using weakref.

This is the last Edit of my Question:
The Reason i was asking this question was my approach to get TextInput from automatic generated TextInput Widgets and add these text Inputs to a list.

My Approach was completely wrong, and this is the reason i got stuck. As i found a ton of other people asking for the same reason ( getting Textinput from user interface available for py logic) going for the same approach, getting stuck
i do link a "Solution" which worked for me and enabled me to access TextInput without Widget Id:

[Right approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48021882/get-value-of-dynamic-add-textbox)

I do really hope to save you guys some time. Anyway i marked the Answer as right because it given the solution for what i did ask for ( my Bad ).

I am really struggling to reference TextInput Widgets after generate them by User Input.
I was trying walk() options already.

```
self.ids.grid.clear_widgets([i for i in self.ids.grid.children])
        label1 = Label(text="Periode")
        label2 = Label(text="Gross Income d Geschäftsfeldes")
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(label1)
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(label2)
        for i in range(int(ButtonsZähler[0])):
            label = Label(text="GI in Periode: -" + str(i+1))
            text = TextInput(text=' ')
            self.ids.grid.add_widget(label)
            btn1 = Button(text="Close", )
            self.ids.grid.add_widget(text)
            self.ids['text'] = weakref.ref(text)
```

and i have the following kivy code related to this:

:
name: 'RisikokapitalOperativesRisikoIII'

```
GridLayout:
    id: Peter
    cols: 1
    GridLayout:
        id: grid
        name : grid
        cols: 2
    GridLayout:
        id: grid2
        cols: 2
        Button:
            id:zurruck
            text:"Abbrechen"
            on_press:

                app.root.total_button = 5
            on_release:
                root.redo()
                app.root.current = "RisikokapitalOperativesRisikoI"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
```

i dont know how to reference the text Input. Labels and Text Input are shown correctly. I want to add all text Inputs by User to one List. I have no clue how to work aroound the fact add_widget ist not abled to generate id in my kv File ?

kind regards

UPDATE:
By Using the already given Help i could retrive the following information (a part of a list its given all widgets but i just post one  ) in my console:

```
<weakref at 0x000001E761011D60; to 'TextInput' at 0x000001E760FFC7B0>
```

Wurst
[<kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput object at 0x000001E760FFC7B0>,

I would like to be abled to acces the TextInput given by User and add this input to a list. As the Documentation is written for experienced users which i am not maybe someone is willing to give a easy to understandable Example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code:

```
self.ids['text'] = weakref.ref(text)
```

is adding the `TextInput` to the `ids`, but it is setting the key for all of them to the same value (`text`). So, if you try to access the `TextInput` using `self.ids.text` you will only get the last `TextInput` added. You can work around this problem by making unique keys for each `TextInput`, maybe like:

```
self.ids[str(i+1)] = weakref.ref(text)
```

or just keep you own list of the `TextInput` widgets:

```
self.ti_list = []
.
.
.
for i in range(int(ButtonsZähler[0])):
    .
    .
    .
    self.ti_list.append(text)
```

When looking at your code that creates the `TextInputs`, the only thing that differentiates the `TextInputs` is the value of `i`. Everything else is the same. So that is used to record the `TextInputs`. In the case of using `ids`, you would access a `TextInput` contents by its vale of `i` as `self.ids[str(i+1)].text`. Similarly, if you use a list, you can access the same as `self.ti_list[i].text`.

Comment: Hey could you please add how to acces the referenced Object ? I need to store all TextInput into one list. As your Solution is doing what i asked for i will accept it later on anyways.

Comment: I had accept the fact there a less  difficult / more easy was to do what i asked for. So i had to edit my Question again. Thanks for your Help i do appreciate it. When i woke up and saw someone tried to help me monday  blues was straight gone

Comment: Thats a nice addition  ins response to my Updates. For Today iam pretty done with experimental or new Stuff, but i will give it a try tomorrow.  IThanks man